# How to free Adjency Linked List allocated memory?

Tags: c, memory-management, free, dynamic-memory-allocation

I would like to free an Adjency Linked List memory
Here is my data structs and two function which can allocate memory for the graph.
How can I free the allocated memory ? 
Thanks for the help

```
struct ListPoint {
    int dest;
    int weight;
    struct ListPoint* next;
};
struct List {
    struct ListPoint* head;
};
struct Graf {
    int V;
    struct List* array;
};
struct ListPoint* newAdjencyListPoint(int dest, int weight)
{
    struct ListPoint* newPoint =
        (struct ListPoint*)malloc(sizeof(struct ListPoint));
    newPoint->dest = dest;
    newPoint->weight = weight; 
    newPoint->next = NULL;
    return newPoint;
}
struct Graf* createGraph(int V)
{
    struct Graf* graf = (struct Graf*)malloc(sizeof(struct Graf));
    graf->V = V;
    graf->array= (struct List*)malloc(V * sizeof(struct List));
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < V; ++i)
        graf->array[i].head = NULL;
    return graf;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will problaby be what you are looking for:

```
freeLinkedList(struct List list){
   struct ListPoint *aux,*it = list.head;
   while(it != NULL){ //free a node and go to the next one
      aux = it->next;
      free(it);
      it = aux;
   }
}
freeAdjList(struct Graf* adj_list){
   for(int i=0;i<adj_list->V;i++) //free each linked list
      freeLinkedList(adj_list->array[i]);
   free(adj_list->array); //free the linked list array
   free(adj_list); //free the adj matrix itself
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I got the following error from Microsoft Visual Studio 2013
Error 1 error C2440: 'function' : cannot convert from 'List' to 'List*'

The problem is in the "for" loop: freeLinkedList(adj_list->array[i]);
adj_list has a red underline

Comment: Error: Argument of type "struct List" is incompatible with parameter of type "struct List * "